# Can we automate the creation of planner plans inside existing Teams channels using power automate flows

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I have a SharePoint list >> and when creating a new item >> i will submit those info:-

1. Title
2. Existing SharePoint Teams url or name
3. New Channel name
4. New Planner Plan name

Then I need to automate the following:-

1. Create a new channel inside the existing Teams
2. Create a new planner plan inside the newly created channel..

So is this possible to automate using power automate? as I cannot find any built-in connectors to achieve the above.

Currently i have this, where i am getting the related teams + create a standard channel: -

[image]

but i were not able to find any action to create a new Planner plan under the newly created channel:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev i tried to do thi using the built-in connectors but nothing worked for me...

Comment: The above is possible in Power Automate. Update the question with what flow you have so far and where you are stuck. Take it a step at a time and ask for help for one particular blocker.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev updated my question with more details of what i currently have. can you have a look please?

Comment: @SamNseir yes sure, i should have done this before, i provided what i currently have so far and where i am stuck. thanks

Comment: Add an action to create a new Planner plan. Use the "Create a task" action from the Planner connector. Provide the newly created channel ID as the Bucket ID and the New Planner Plan name as the Task title.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT you mean i can use "Create a task" action to create a new planner? i thought it is used only to create new tasks inside existing plans

Comment: You need to make a call via Graph API - see https://michelcarlo.com/2021/09/04/creating-planner-plans-using-power-automate/

Comment: @SamNseir so seems i will need a premium license to do what i need?

Comment: No, you do not need a premium license to call the Planner API in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT but i can not call Graph API from power automate unless i use a premium connector/action.. there is not any standard built-in actions in power automate to call graph API.. as far i know

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. What I meant in above post is you don't need premium license to run planner Graph API in Microsoft Graph. But if you need to use this API within Power Automate via HTTP connector you will need premium license. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmO0s.png